# Why does Cortana need to know how pronounce my name?

Tags: cortana, speech

As you can see, Cortana has an option where I can inform my name and even teach her how to pronounce it:

[image]

But since I'm using Cortana for almost a year, I never made her speak my name. The only related thing is when I open the search and is my name there.

In which case does Cortana pronounce our names?

Comment: Just ask her what is your name? :P she will speak. Jokes apart. Cortana used to speak name somewhere I don't remember exactly but I think when you kept the search key pressed which opens cortana by default in listening mode it asked you by your name. Not sure as in windows 10 TP it doesn't speaks while this.

Comment: @Deep When in listening mode she just wait you ask.

Answer (score 4):

The only case in which I have ever heard Cortana speak my name is if I ask her what my name is. AFAIK she never speaks it otherwise.  I'm guessing that they want Cortana to be able to pronounce your name in case they *do* decide to have Cortana speak your name more often, rather than trying to make everyone teach their name *after* she needs to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 10 Preview on your desktop/notebook and press the mic, she asks how she can help [your name].

There is also this feature when a Windows Phone is locked and you lost it. The person who finds the phone can ask Cortana to whom the phone belongs. Can't find a source at the moment.

Do not forget that Microsoft wants to make Cortana a **personal** assistant who fits your lifestyle. So perhaps this is just for future versions.